# Restructuring and reformatting json api output data

Tags: python, json, api

Hello I have some json api output data that I am trying to restructure/reformat. Here is a sample of the output:

```
{
"playergamelogs: {
  "gamelogs": [
    {
       "game" : {
         "date" : "2016-10-13"
         "id" : "32637},
       "player": {
         "ID": "4419"},
       "team" : {
         "id" : "16}, 
       "stats" : {
          "minutes": "10"}
      },
      {
       "game": {
         "date" : "2016-10-17"
         "id" : "33737},
       "player": {
         "ID": "4419"},
       "team" : {
         "id" : "16
       }, 
       "stats" : {
          "minutes": "10"
```

What I would like to do is group the data by player id (or name). For example:

```
`{
   "playerlogs" : [
     {
      "player" : {
        "ID" : "4419"
        "team" : {
          "id" : "16"
        }, 
        "gamelogs" : [
          {
            "game" : {}
            "game" : {}
          }
         }
       "player" : {
         ....
       }
      }`
```

The best way that I can think to accomplish this is nested for loops using `dict.items()` and if statements to match the appropriate player ID's. I am having trouble with the most efficient way to go about restructuring. I am fairly new to python and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What've you tried so far?

Comment: No need to go for "the most efficient way" from the start. Just make sure it works and care about optimization later.

Comment: sorry did not want to clutter the initial post. I have added what I have tried above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able solve my initial question and reformat the original data:

```
for i in range(0,len(dataedit)):
playerID = dataedit[i]["player"]["ID"]
if not any(p.get('player',{}).get('ID',{}) == playerID for p in playerlog):
    playerlog.append({})
    playerlog[x]["player"] = dataedit[i]["player"]
    x+=1
gameID = dataedit[i]["game"]["id"]
playerlog[x-1]["player"]["game" + gameID] = dataedit[i]["game"]
playerlog[x-1]["player"]["game" + gameID]["stats"] = dataedit[i]["stats"]
playerlog[x-1]["player"]["game" + gameID]["team"] = dataedit[i]["team"]
```

As I am still learning, I would love to get feedback/comments on how to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding your transformation logic into python code I suggest to check MongoDB. It is a JSON based document database and you can create such queries with it.

Here is a very simple example:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Your data is more complex, but player is similar to cust_id and game to amount in the example.

Comment: thanks for the response and info! I am trying to head in the mongodb direction. I would like to eventually store the api data in mongoDB. I was trying to clean up the data before adding to mongoDB. Is it better to just store the raw output in MongoDB and then clean data using queries?

Comment: If you anyway want to use MongoDB, then why not use it? It is easier to use an existing tool than reinvent it. I would create a MongoDB collection and store the items in your "gamelogs" list as separate documents.